# The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, methods, .net-assembly

I get this error when I publish this aspx file on my domain:

> The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

My domain: http://english.bayynat.org.lb/Istiftaat/Index-Send.aspx

I loaded the specific namespace to the same file as it follows:

```
        <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="IndexPage.data" %>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing" %>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>
        <%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
```

then I write this code inside the same file:

```
    <script runat="server">
            public void btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    var from_mail = "test@gmail.com";
                    var to_mail = "test@gmail.com";
                    const string Password = "******";
                    string mail_subject = txtSubject.Text.ToString();
                    string mail_message = "From: " + txtname.Text + "\n";
                    mail_message += "Email: " + txtEmail.Text + "\n";
                    mail_message += "Subject: " + txtSubject.Text + "\n";
                    mail_message += "Message: " + txtmessage.Text + "\n";
    
    
                    var stmp = new SmtpClient();
                    {
                        stmp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        stmp.Port = 587;
                        stmp.EnableSsl = true;
                        stmp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                        stmp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from_mail, Password);
                        stmp.Timeout = 20000;
                    }
                    stmp.Send(from_mail, to_mail, mail_subject, mail_message);
    
                    Confirm.Text = "Thank you for your Email";
    
                    txtname.Text = "";
                    txtEmail.Text = "";
                    txtSubject.Text = "";
                    txtmessage.Text = "";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Confirm.Text = "Something went wrong! Please try again";
                }
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: Not causing your problem but your `var smtp` isn't using the initializer pattern I think you think it is. Remove the `;` and all the `smtp.` inside the `{ }`

Comment: Just want to double check, is `var` available in the version of C# you're using? it came along in C# 3 (.netfw 3.5) - if the project is earlier you'll need to target 3.5+ or use explicit types. The mangling of your object initializer on `var smtp` into a form that the compiler doesn't complain about (i.e. not an initializer at all, just a needlessly indented scoped block of set statements) further makes me think that you're on a very old C#